# os.stat on Windows "nul" file

Tags: python, windows, dev-null

Why can't I call `os.stat` on the special Windows file `nul`?

```
>>> import os
>>> os.stat('nul')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
WindowsError: [Error 87] The parameter is incorrect: 'nul'
```

I can open it:

```
>>> f = open('nul', 'r')
>>> f.read(10)
''
```

I was hoping to check for special files like `/dev/null` and `nul` in a cross-platform way with `stat.S_ISCHR` and was surprised to find that I can't stat a file that I can open.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to this old Python bug, it's supposed to be that way:

http://bugs.python.org/issue1311

Answer (score 2):

This is the behavior of the underlying Win32 `GetFileAttributesEx()` and `CreateFile()` functions, which are eventually called by `os.stat()` and `open()`.